# Maximum wavelength for measuring a certain sized object?

Tags: waves

If you want to measure a certain sized object, whether atoms or building etc., what is the maximum size of wavelength that you can use? Is there an idea like Nyquist?

Presumably, a wavelength of exactly the same size would give you the idea that the object is there, but if you positioned two items 1 wavelength apart, then you would get two readings? Possibly the max. wavelength, should be the minimum distance likely between objects?

I would be interested to know if there are any formal thoughts on this?

Comment: See this article, it may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system

Comment: And look up Airy and Abbe resolution.